# How to send a selected DropDownList item ID To ActionMethod

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to send the id of selected item in DropDownList to a ActionMethod .... when I tried this code and select the item I want then click submit , I got no result ..

My VM To get the list of item :

```
 vm.Group = new SelectList(db.Groups.Where(p => p.User_Id == user_id && p.state==1), "Group_id", "Group_name");
```

My view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("group_list", Model.Group, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
<button type="button" data-id="@Model.Book.Book_id" class="BGButton btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

My JS Call :

```
$('.BGButton').click(function () {

    var myId = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("Insert", "Group")?Book_id=' + myId+"&Group_id="+@Model.Group,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#myElem').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
            $('#myElem').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
        },
        failure: function (response) {

            alert("Failure");
        }
    });
});
```

My action I'm trying to reach / sending data to it :

```
public ActionResult Insert(int? Book_id , string group_list)
    {

                var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                GroupBook GrpBook = new GroupBook()
                    {
                        Book_Id = (int)Book_id,
                        User_Id = x.ToString(),
                        Group_id=Convert.ToInt16(group_list)

                };
                    db.GroupBooks.Add(GrpBook);

    }
```

When I try the pervious code , I got no result (No calling) , How I can fix that and make it work , and thanks ...

Comment: ones check in your browser developer console for any errors.. if any errors let us know that.we can help then

Comment: Hello , Actually until now I have no problem , because the problem seems in Js call Method .. Because when I tried to get the book id only and in the action method I added manually group_id = 1 it's works and added the data to db and the js was like this (url: '@Url.Action("Insert", "Group")?Book_id=' + myId) but when I tried to send the group_id from the dropdownlist with the js to the action I got no result or error ...

Comment: ok, BTW i didnt get what is the purpose of `data-id="@Model.Book.Book_id"` in button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in button click

```
$('.BGButton').click(function() {

  var myId = $(this).data('id');
  var groupId = $('#Group_id').val();//assuming Group_id is your dropdown id

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("Insert", "Group")?Book_id=' + myId + "&Group_id=" + groupId,
        success: function(response) {
          $('#myElem').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
          $('#myElem').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
        },
        failure: function(response) {

          alert("Failure");
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: check your dropdown markup in browser.is it displaying values?what is the id of the dropdown?

Comment: Yes it's display set of items : 
<select id="Group_id" class="form-control" name="group_list"><option value="1">PPU Group</option>
<option value="10">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</option>
</select>

Comment: got it.. in your action method parameter name is `string group_list` change it to `string Group_id`